# C++ Ant simulation: How to move element from a std::list to another area

Tags: c++, stdlist

I am currently trying an Ant simulation.

The area looks like this:

```
class Area
{
    public:
    Area(Area *north, Area *east, Area *south, Area *west);
    ~Area();

    Area* getSouth();
    Area* getEast();
    Area* getWest();
    Area* getNorth();

    void setSouth(Area* south);
    void setEast(Area* east);
    void setWest(Area* west);
    void setNorth(Area* north);

    void printInfo();

    std::list<Item*> Liste;

    private:
    Area *south, *east, *west, *north;
};
```

And inside the list I store the objects that are currently on the field, like ants, food, anthill.

When I want to move an Ant from one field to another I used this code:

```
void Ant::move(){

    // Random movement
    srand(time(NULL))
    int direction = rand() % 4; // 0.. north, 1.. east, 2.. south, 3.. west
    cout << direction << endl;

    if(direction == 0 && moved == 0){

        Area* help = this->area->getNorth();
        cout << "I want to move to " << help << endl;

        if(help != NULL){

            this->area->Liste.remove(this);
            this->area = this->area->getNorth();
            this->age++;
            this->moved=1;
            this->area->Liste.push_back(this);

            cout << "moved north to " << this->area << endl;
        }
    }
```

However this doesn't work, and I think the problem lies within the list and my approach to move the ant to a neighboring field. The first ant can change the field (or so it seems by the console output) but the next field procudes a segmentation fault during execution.

How can I make this movement better? I am grateful for any tips.

Comment: It compiles without problems, Qt Creator as IDE. Besides: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove/ there is a remove function?

Comment: Is `this->area` guaranteed to be non-null? Have you overloaded `operator<<` for `Area*`, by any chance? These would be two possible causes that I can think of. (I'm not going to comment on style, choice of data structures and so on at this stage.)

Comment: Yes this->area is non-null. Not overloaded.

Comment: Then I'd say there's another problem in some other part of the code. I'd try to find where it fails using a debugger.

Comment: @user3549596, I stand corrected.